How to make showBottomSheet use the root navigator and render outside of it's current navigator
I'm trying to show a tutorial like card that pops out at the bottom and the user can press a button or drag down to dismiss it. When I use to showModalBottomSheet with the property useRootNavigator set to true it covers the bottom navigation bar I have set up. but when I use showBottomSheet, it doesn't have the useRootNavigator property and also it renders above the bottom bar navigator which is outside of the internal navigator.
My use case requires me to show the background without covering it, which is what showModalBottomSheet does.
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => ... ,
      useRootNavigator: true,
);

showBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => ... ,
);


Use showBottomSheet like below... hope it helps
             showBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Container(); // Replace with your actual bottom sheet widget
                  },
                ).closed.whenComplete(() {
                  Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
                });

